# Disabled radio button still clickable

Tags: angular

Well, I'm having a problem with my radio buttons, two of them appears disabled and the other two no.
This is my mock where you can see my problem: [mock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoWWl.png)

My code is this (all inside a form), and the [disabled]="accion === acciones.VER" means that when you enter to the form from buttom "VER" all of that should be disabled:

```
<div class="form-group mb-3 col">
                <label for="actividad">Actividad:</label>
                <div class="form-check-inline">
                    <input [disabled]="accion === acciones.VER" type="radio"  class="form-check-input ml-3" id="actividad" name="actividad"  value= "Entrada" [(ngValue)]="Entrada" [(ngModel)]="actividad.tipoActividad" checked/>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="actividad">
                        Entrada
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check-inline">
                    <input [disabled]="accion === acciones.VER" type="radio"  class="form-check-input ml-3" id="actividad2" name="actividad"  value="Salida" [(ngValue)]="Salida" [(ngModel)]="actividad.tipoActividad">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="actividad">
                        Salida
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mb-3 col">
                <label for="ejecucion">Ejecución:</label>
                <div class="form-check-inline">
                    <input [disabled]="accion === acciones.VER" type="radio"  class="form-check-input ml-3" id="ejecucion" name="ejecucion" value="Sincrona" [(ngValue)]="Sincrona" [(ngModel)]="actividad.tipoEjecucion" checked/>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="ejecucion">
                        Síncrona
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check-inline">
                    <input [disabled]="accion === acciones.VER" type="radio"  class="form-check-input ml-3" id="ejecucion2" name="ejecucion" value="Asincrona" [(ngValue)]="Asincrona" [(ngModel)]="actividad.tipoEjecucion">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="ejecucion">
                        Asíncrona
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Thank you in advance

EDIT:

Thank you @diabolique I edited it, but it wasn't the problem.

EDIT2:
[attr.disabled] worked but it disabled the buttons when i push on "ver" and too when i push on "edit" or "create", I just need to disabled them on "ver" not always. Thank you anyway @diabolique for your time

Comment: Label in Ejecución should be for ejecucion, not for actividad.

Comment: Replace ```[disabled]``` with ```[attr.disabled]```.